# Custom Linq query for Entity Framework & ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have been working on an ASP.NET MVC app using Entity Framework. Also, it's my first time developing an ASP.NET MVC app. I have been struggling (close to a month of trying and googling) to write a linq query to display results in jQuery datatable for the below SQL query. It involves various left joins and some columns have null values. It would be great if someone could help me out on this. There are 3 tables as below

1. Assets
2. Category
3. Term

```
SELECT 
    Asset.Name AS Name,
    Asset.Type AS Type,
    Asset.Parent_Asset AS "Parent Asset",
    Cat.Category AS Category,
    Cat.Parent_Category AS "Parent Category",
    T.BUSINESS_TERM AS "Business Term",
    T.SHORT_DESCRIPTION AS Description
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         CH.DISPLAY AS Name,
         CH.TYPE AS Type,
         PA.DISPLAY AS Parent_Asset,
         CH.CATEGORY_INT_ID
     FROM 
         [Metadata].[dbo].[Asset] CH
     LEFT JOIN 
         [Metadata].[dbo].[Asset] PA ON PA.PARENT_ASSET_ID = CH.ASSET_INT_ID) Asset
     LEFT JOIN 
         (SELECT
              CH.DISPLAY AS Category,
              PA.DISPLAY AS Parent_Category,
              CH.CATEGORY_INT_ID AS Category_Id
          FROM 
              [METADATA].[dbo].[Category] CH
          LEFT JOIN 
              [METADATA].[dbo].[Category] PA ON PA.PARENT_CATEGORY_ID = CH.CATEGORY_INT_ID) Cat ON Asset.CATEGORY_INT_ID = Cat.Category_Id
     LEFT JOIN 
         [Metadata].[dbo].[Term] T ON T.CATEGORY_INT_ID = Cat.Category_Id
```

Comment: Title and body talk about just "Entity Framework"- but the tag says "EF Core" - so which are you really using? Those are **not** the same! Certain things behave differently in EF Core vs. "legacy" EF .... also: if you *are* using EF Core - are you also using ASP.NET **Core** MVC ?? Please be **precise** in how you describe your dev environment, and set the **correct** tags!

Comment: @marc_s I ll try to be precise and clear next time

Answer (score 0):

Create Stored Procedure in the database where the application is connected

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetAsset
AS
BEGIN

SELECT 
    Asset.Name AS Name,
    Asset.Type AS Type,
    Asset.Parent_Asset AS ParentAsset,
    Cat.Category AS Category,
    Cat.Parent_Category AS ParentCategory,
    T.BUSINESS_TERM AS BusinessTerm,
    T.SHORT_DESCRIPTION AS Description
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        CH.DISPLAY AS Name,
        CH.TYPE AS Type,
        PA.DISPLAY AS Parent_Asset,
        CH.CATEGORY_INT_ID
    FROM 
        [Metadata].[dbo].[Asset] CH
    LEFT JOIN 
        [Metadata].[dbo].[Asset] PA ON PA.PARENT_ASSET_ID = CH.ASSET_INT_ID) Asset
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT
             CH.DISPLAY AS Category,
             PA.DISPLAY AS Parent_Category,
             CH.CATEGORY_INT_ID AS Category_Id
         FROM 
             [METADATA].[dbo].[Category] CH
         LEFT JOIN 
             [METADATA].[dbo].[Category] PA ON PA.PARENT_CATEGORY_ID = CH.CATEGORY_INT_ID) Cat ON Asset.CATEGORY_INT_ID = Cat.Category_Id
    LEFT JOIN 
        [Metadata].[dbo].[Term] T ON T.CATEGORY_INT_ID = Cat.Category_Id
);  
END
```

Create class to get data:

```
public class TestAsset
{
        public string Name           { get; set; }
        public string Type           { get; set; }
        public string ParentAsset    { get; set; }
        public string Category       { get; set; }
        public string ParentCategory { get; set; }
        public string BusinessTerm   { get; set; }
        public string Description    { get; set; }
}
```

Get data in your Context

```
 public class YourContext : DbContext
 {
    public List<TestAsset> GetAssets()
    {
        return this.Query<TestAsset>.FromSql("Exec sp_GetAsset").ToList();
    }
 }
```

Use GetAssets Method

```
using (YourContext context = new YourContext())
{       
   var list = context.GetAssets();
}
```

Comment: I am not able to import views in my model. I get the following error:                       Error 6013: The table/view 'Metadata.dbo.vwAssets' does not have a primary key defined and no valid primary key could be inferred. This table/view has been excluded. To use the entity, you will need to review your schema, add the correct keys, and uncomment it.

Comment: You can use Stored Procedure too. For example: Create Procedure sp_GetAssets Begin "samet query" END.  After that you can get data from sp. For example: context.TestAsset.FromSql("EXEC sp_GetAssets").ToList(); Notes: You have to create class and use in context like TestAssets. And all class properties have to be same with sp columns. Both name and data type.

Comment: This is created when I import sp in my model:                                                          
 public virtual ObjectResult<sp_GetAsset_Result> sp_GetAsset()
        {
            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<sp_GetAsset_Result>("sp_GetAsset");
        }                                                                                                                                    How do I access it in controller

Comment: Can you try this:                                                                                                         
        using (YourContext context = new YourContext())
        { 
            var list = context.sp_GetAsset();
        }

Comment: I am getting null values in all columns

Comment: All class properties have to be same with sp columns. Both name and data type. Can you check thats.

Comment: I double checked it. Its same. Any other suggestions. I get this error. DataTables warning: table id=myTable - Requested unknown parameter 'Name' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Comment: Can you take a photo and send of where you used the sp_GetAsset method?

Comment: How can i do that

Comment: Hey @Hidayet . Any other suggestions for the solutions

Comment: Thanks . It worked. I was missing some assembly reference.